# Bitwise operator in apache derby

Tags: function, derby, bitwise-operators

I would like to know if Derby supports bitwise operators in SQL statements. 
I can see in feature lists truth-value tests as YES.
Following is the link of the same:

```
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsql9241891.html
```

I want to execute a query like this:
SELECT a & b FROM APP.TEST;

Thanks

Tried implementing the above functionality by defining a function in derby:

```
CREATE FUNCTION BitAnd(a SMALLINT, b SMALLINT) RETURNS SMALLINT
    PARAMETER STYLE JAVA NO SQL LANGUAGE JAVA
    EXTERNAL NAME 'derby.routines.BitAnd.bitAnd';
```

Next, I called the following to have the above function on derby class path,
CALL SQLJ.install_jar

```
('path\to\db\functions.jar', 'APP.functions', 0);
```

CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY

```
('derby.database.classpath', 'APP.functions');
```

successfully executed the above sp calls, following which jar directory was created with following file as `path\to\db\jar\APP\FUNCTIONS.jar.G1340195863482`

But when i try calling this function in my java code:

```
deleteAgentStats = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select bitAnd(a,b) AS \"result\" from APP.TEST");
ResultSet andResult = deleteAgentStats.executeQuery();
if(andResult.next()){
        System.out.println("heyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy :: 
"+andResult.getInt("result"));
}
```

I get the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The class 'derby.routines.BitAnd' does not exist or is inaccessible. This can happen if the class is not public.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
    at primary.db.AgentStatisticsDAO.deleteAgentStatistics(AgentStatisticsDAO.java:507)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The class 'derby.routines.BitAnd' does not exist or is inaccessible. This can happen if the class is not public.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: 'derby.routines.BitAnd: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: derby.routines.BitAnd
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1643)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1488)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.reflect.ReflectClassesJava2.loadClassNotInDatabaseJar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.reflect.DatabaseClasses.loadApplicationClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.loader.ClassInspector.getClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.loader.ClassInspector.accessible(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.verifyClassExist(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.StaticMethodCallNode.bindExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.JavaToSQLValueNode.bindExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.bindExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.bindExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindExpressions(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a good case for using Derby's Java extensibility. Consider writing your bit-manipulation routines in Java, then calling them from your Derby SQL: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbySQLroutines

Comment: I created a derby function but i cannot call the function. I always get 'ClassNotFoundException' on calling that function.

Comment: Well, your code has to be available in the Derby classpath, since it's the Derby engine that invokes your code. In the embedded configuration, that means it has to be in the application classpath. In the client/server configuration, that means it has to be in the Network Server's classpath. Here's a nice blog covering these topics: http://www.danvega.org/blog/2010/2/17/Creating-Apache-Derby-Custom-Functions-Part-2